# Skip resume in GRUB2 after hibernating

Tags: linux, hibernate, grub2

I use openSUSE Tumbleweed (x86-64). It uses GRUB2.

Sleep and resume works while hibernate and resume freezes the machine.

Today I accediantely hibernated the machine. Now it does not resume.

To skip resume and allow normal boot I tried several key configurations to access GRUB2 menu but failed. It always skips to resume immediately.

I have already tried <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> just after machine is powered.

So my question is whether there is a key combination so that GRUB2 menu appears or any other way to skip resume and continue to normal boot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a rescue disk/USB and boot through disk/USB.

Mount `/boot` partition and rename `/boot/grub2/grubenv` to `/boot/grub2/grubenv2`.

It allows GRUB2 menu to appear.